# Saving results to destination table costs

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm wondering what kind of insert saving the results of a large query (with multiple joins and unions) to a destination (day partitioned) table is. 
Currently on a GC VM I execute these queries, save the results in a local temporary CSV and upload these CSVs to their respective tables.

This is fairly ineffective (not as fast as it can be and uses quite a lot of VM resources). However, it is cheap, since CSV loading jobs are free. If I were to save the query results into a destination table (appending to old data which already consists of 100M+ rows), would those incur insertion streaming costs? This is what I'd like to avoid since $0.02/MB can rack up quite a bit since we're adding a lot of data on a daily basis.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: how do you define 'not as fast', describe your phases, what's the espected fast duration? What resources you find limiting?

Comment: The resources I find limiting are the fact that I have to download the results, write those in several CSVs locally and then use load jobs to upload those. It's just the cheapest Google VM so it's not blazingly fast and I'm on a fairly strict time schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Inside Bigquery running a query and saving to destination table results you

- query price (anyway you pay it)
- storage price (new data gets accumulated to the table - choose partitioned)
- no streaming costs

If you have data outside of BQ and you end up adding the data to BQ

- if you use load (that's free)
- streaming insert (has a cost component)
- storage of the new data, the table you added

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering what kind of insert saving the results of a large query (with multiple joins and unions) to a destination (day partitioned) table is.
>   ... if I were to save the query results into a destination table (appending to old data which already consists of 100M+ rows), would those incur insertion streaming costs?

Setting the destination table for query job is **the most effective** way of getting result of that query being added to the existing table. It DOES NOT incur any extra cost related to streaming as there is no streaming happening here at all

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, clear answer! Maybe I'm confused on what streaming actually is; are they just INSERTs? I'm coming from an old SQL background so I'm still learning the BQ way of doing things.

Comment: Streaming insert is when you do one by one INSERTs. Load is when you do using files up to 5TB.